# AsnContentException: The provided data is tagged with 'Universal' class value '16', but it should have been 'Universal' class value '2'

Tags: c#, .net, security, rsa, bouncycastle

I'm trying to create an RSA keypair using BouncyCastle and then try to import generated public key and I'm receiving the following error

`AsnContentException: The provided data is tagged with 'Universal' class value '16', but it should have been 'Universal' class value '2'.`

The code is the following

```cs
RsaKeyPairGenerator rsaKeyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
rsaKeyPairGenerator.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));
    
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = rsaKeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
    
PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(keys.Private);
byte[] serializedPrivateBytes = privateKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
    
SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keys.Public);
byte[] serializedPublicBytes = publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
    
RSA publicRsaKey = RSA.Create();
publicRsaKey.ImportRSAPublicKey(serializedPublicBytes, out _);
```

Anyone know why am I getting this?

Comment: `ImportRSAPublicKey` expects a certain specific public key format based on PKCS #1. Your public key is formatted as a SubjectPublicKeyInfo (aka SPKI) Asn1 object, so you should use `RSA.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` to import it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks for your reply. How can I generate a PKCS#1 format based on the code above so that I can use ```publicRsaKey.ImportRSAPublicKey``` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already described in the comment by President James K. Polk, the exported public key `serializedPublicBytes` is a DER encoded key in X.509/SPKI format that can be imported with `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`, while `ImportRSAPublicKey()` expects a DER encoded public key in PKCS#1 format.

For completeness: The PKCS#1 format can be easily derived from `publicKeyInfo` with the following addition to the posted code:

```cs
RsaPublicKeyStructure rsaPublicKey = RsaPublicKeyStructure.GetInstance(publicKeyInfo.ParsePublicKey());
byte[] pkcs1Der = rsaPublicKey.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
```

so that the import can also be done with `ImportRSAPublicKey()` passing `pkcs1Der`, or if the public key is needed in PKCS#1 format.

Comment: thanks. That did the trick. Been searching for this and didn't find it anywhere. Hope your answer helps other people.

Answer (score 1):

For any future searchers looking at this, you can also run into this error when trying to import a public key that's from [Google's Tink cryptography libraries](https://github.com/google/tink).

In this case, the public key value may actually be a base64-encoded protobuf value, which would need to be deserialized to get the actual embedded public key, according to [these protobuf definitions](https://github.com/google/tink).